# How to use a variable in the MasterPage

Tags: custom-masterpage

We have an image in our masterpage that needs to have the source file automatically changed about once a week. I figgure I can set the image source to a variable/property I create at the Web Application level that could be changed, but unsure how to reference that value from within the master page. This is the last step in our automation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant solution that I can think of is custom expression builder. Think about a built in expression builder like SPUrl with syntax like:

```
<%$ SPUrl:~sitecollection/images/... %>
```

Similarly, you can create your own expression like

```
<img src="<%$ MyCustomExpression:ChangeThisImage.jpeg %>" />
```

Check the article below to  understand this concept and implement it yourself.

[Using Expression Builders in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx)

Comment: This is what I had been trying to find, I instead went with the use of delegate control which also suited my needs perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go this no-code way instead?

Because in SharePoint designer code blocks are not allowed, you won't be able to use ASP.NET inline expressions.
So, If you want to remain within the boundaries of SharePoint Designer, you can simply add in your masterpage a normal html img tag, whose src points to the SiteAssets library:

```
<img src="../../SiteAssets/image.jpg" />
```

Then, when you need to change the image once a week, just rename the current image.jpg to something different like image_old.jpg and upload the new image.jpg.

**UPDATE**:

just to clarify my answer and the diatribe about the usage of relative paths in the src attribute.
As correctly remarked by Robert Lindgren, relative paths in master pages have some limitations that one should be aware of (one over all, they won't work when inheriting the master page in a sub site). nonethless, they still can be used when you want to use a master page in a specific site, a sub site for example, and you don't intend to have it inherited by other sub sites.
Moreover, the whole matter of relative vs absolute paths, is distracting from the main point of my answer, which is why not using a fixed image name and just replacing the image with a new one when needed.

Again, as most of the time with SharePoint, this is a workaround, a dirty hack or whatever you want to call it, but when one of the requirements is staying within the boundaries imposed by the native functionalities and SharePoint designer, there isn't really much that one can do without accepting some compromises.

Comment: This would work terribly with multiple levels if sub webs, HNSC's etc. Hardcoding a URL (especially a relative one) will always bring great limitations

Comment: I'm well aware of the limitations, but it's definitely a viable solution. Not a universal, will-always-work one, I agree, but still is an option

Comment: You did not mention any limitations in your answer, I wanted to clarify the limitations

Comment: Glad to see your update :)